# Node.js EventEmitter: How to bind a class context to the event listener and then remove this listener

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, typescript, eventemitter

Is there a way to access to the class context in the event listener method with possibility to remove the listener?

**Example 1:**

```
import {EventEmitter} from "events";

export default class EventsExample1 {
    private emitter: EventEmitter;

    constructor(private text: string) {
        this.emitter = new EventEmitter();

        this.emitter.addListener("test", this.handleTestEvent);
        this.emitter.emit("test");
    }


    public dispose() {
        this.emitter.removeListener("test", this.handleTestEvent);
    }

    private handleTestEvent() {
        console.log(this.text);
    }
}
```

In this example removing the listener works, but the `handleTestEvent()`method has no access to the class context using `this`. `this` points to EventEmitter context, so `this.text` is not accessible.

**Example 2:**

```
import {EventEmitter} from "events";

export default class EventsExample2 {
    private emitter: EventEmitter;

    constructor(private text: string) {
        this.emitter = new EventEmitter();

        this.emitter.addListener("test", this.handleTestEvent.bind(this));
        this.emitter.emit("test");
    }

    public dispose() {
        this.emitter.removeListener("test", this.handleTestEvent);
    }

    private handleTestEvent() {
        console.log(this.text);
    }
}
```

In this example, I'm using the [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function to bind a context of the class to the event listener. Now `handleTestEvent` method has access to the class context using `this` => `this.text` is accessible, but listener cannot be removed with [`removeListener`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_eventname_listener) - it seems that `bind` creates a new anonymous function, so there is no reference to the bounded listener.

**Example 3:**

```
import {EventEmitter} from "events";

export default class EventsExample3 {
    private emitter: EventEmitter;

    constructor(private text: string) {
        this.emitter = new EventEmitter();

        this.emitter.addListener("test", () => this.handleTestEvent());
        this.emitter.emit("test");
    }

    public dispose() {
        this.emitter.removeListener("test", this.handleTestEvent);
    }

    private handleTestEvent() {
        console.log(this.text);
    }
}
```

In this example, I'm using an arrow function to preserve a context of the class in the event listener. `handleTestEvent` method has access to the class context using `this`, but listener cannot be removed (there is no reference to the bounded listener as in example 2).

I've tried an alternative event library - [EventEmitter3](https://github.com/primus/eventemitter3) which has a support for custom context for events (class context can be passed as third parameter to the `addListener` function (`this.emitter.addListener("test", this.handleTestEvent, this`), it works perfectly, but I rather want to use the included [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) from Node.js.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do this in the constructor:

```
this.handleTestEvent = this.handleTestEvent.bind(this);
this.emitter.addListener("test", this.handleTestEvent);
```

If you want to use cutting edge, you can use the [proposed bind operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator) as a shortcut:

```
this.handleTestEvent = ::this.handleTestEvent;
this.emitter.addListener("test", this.handleTestEvent);
```

Or use a [property initializer](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) to create a bound method:

```
constructor(private text: string) {
  this.emitter = new EventEmitter();

  this.emitter.addListener("test", this.handleTestEvent);
  this.emitter.emit("test");
}

handleTestEvent = () => {
  console.log(this.text);
}
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Answer (score 1):

I was also unable to remove the listener in a class. This worked for me (see: https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_rawlisteners_eventname)

```
emitter.on('error', this.onError.bind(this));
this.onErrorListener = emitter.rawListeners('error').splice(-1)[0];
...
emitter.off('error', this.onErrorListener);
```