# How to call remove listener on EventEmitter in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

I have below code to add listeners on `EventEmitter`,

```
class MyClass {
  init() {
    this.listener = new EventEmitter();
    this.listener.on('eventName', this.onChange.bind(this));
  }
  onChange() {
    ...
  }
}
```

How can I remove the listener from `EventEmitter`? I can see two different ways:

```
this.listener.removeListener('eventName', this.onChange)
this.listener.removeListener('eventName', this.onChange.bind(this))
```

I wonder which one I should use. Whether I need the `bind` when I remove it?

Comment: You'll need to remove the listener with the original reference. This means you'll have to store the anonymous function returned by `this.onChange.bind(this)` somewhere, such as a private property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js EventEmitter: How to bind a class context to the event listener and then remove this listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820651/node-js-eventemitter-how-to-bind-a-class-context-to-the-event-listener-and-then)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `bind()` or you can use an [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in Node. Arrow Functions will inherit their execution context from the invoking context, which is similar to how `bind()` works and provides the same functionality.

`this.listener.removeListener('eventName', this.onChange)`

The above way of removing a listener won't work if it is being called in a `removeListener(eventName)` style function like the following:

```
const obj = new MyObject()
obj.init()
// This would blow up with a 
// ReferenceError saying you cant call removeListener() on undefined   
obj.listener.removeListener('event')
```

Not sure the use of the `init()` function when you can use a `constructor` with the `class` syntax.

```
constructor() {
  this.listener = new EventEmitter()
  this.boundEventNameHandler = () => this.onChange()
  this.listener.on('eventName', this.boundEventNameHandler)
}
```

You can utilize the bound function for removing a listener within the context of a class using `this`.

```
let boundEventNameHandler = this.boundEventNameHandler
this.listener.removeListener('eventName', this.boundEventNameHandler)`
```

An example of this implemented looks like the following

```
const EventEmitter = require('events')

class MyObject {
  constructor () {
    this.listener = new EventEmitter()
    this.boundEventNameHandler = () => this.onChange()
    this.listener.on('eventName', this.boundEventNameHandler)
  }

  // I would reconsider making this a property of the MyObject class 
  // instead, make onChange() a local function outside the MyObject 
  // class definition because onChange in this example is only used by the 
  // event listener for 'eventName' 
  onChange () {
    console.log('event fired change')
  }

  removeListeners () {
    let boundEventNameHandler = this.boundEventNameHandler
    this.listener.removeListener('eventName', boundEventNameHandler)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. It doesn't work this way and it won't remove a listener because you essentially declare two different lambda functions in .on and .removeListener.

Comment: @user0103 Good catch on the function pointer problem for `removeListener()`. Updated for storing a reference to the function pointer. To this extent, you can use either an arrow function or `.bind(this)`

Answer (score 0):

For TypeScript / ESNext you can use this:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.emitter = new EventEmitter();

        this.emitter.on("event1", this.listener1);
        this.emitter.on("event2", this.listener2);

        this.emitter.removeListener("event1", this.listener1);
        this.emitter.removeListener("event2", this.listener2);

        this.emitter.emit("event1"); // no output
        this.emitter.emit("event2"); // no output
    }

    public listener1 = (e) => {
        console.dir(`listener1`);
    };

    public listener2 = (e) => {
        console.dir(`listener2`);
    };
}
```

Basically you define properties and instantly assign bound functions to them.
 This way you use the same function reference in `.on` and `.removeListener`.